# lejos color sensor problems

Tags: java, colors, sensors, lego-mindstorms

I am currently working on a lejos mindstorms project and trying to utilize the color sensor. The overall goal of the project is to have the robot find a string of christmas lights and follow it. Our test code works with detecting color on regular objects but not on the lights. When I shine the sensor on the lights, all it does is say that the color being shown is black. Is it even possible to read color off a colored light with a color sensor?

Comment: IIRC the color sensors are designed to read reflected light; it's possible it's just being blinded.

Comment: Unfortunatly there seems to be no spec for the senor only a 'Detect both reflected and ambient light!' on the store page. So @DaveNewton is most likely right: don't look into the laser with the remaining eye

Comment: Do you think a transparent medium would help the color sensor read it better? Like a clear plastic top or white piece of paper? When we ran the sensor over the lights before, the only color it would return was black, you are probably correct in that it was being blinded.

Comment: I doubt something clear would help. Paper or partially opaque optics might.

Comment: I tried using notebook paper and I still got the same returned value of black. I have the test program returning the raw values of the colors and whenever I shine the color sensor on just the lights themselves that are maxed out at 1023. After I put a piece of notebook paper on it was giving me values of between 750 and close to 900. It clearly helped a little bit but is still being blinded. Do you think construction paper would work better? Also what you you mean by opaque optics? What would you suggest for that?

Answer (score 1):

I am working in a club where we build robots with Mindstorms for multiple years now, and I am sure that's it's not possible to read the color of a light with a color sensor, neither with the ones from the EV3 set nor the NXT ones.

---

Here's why:
The color sensor works by emitting a light onto a surface, and based on how much of which color is absorbed by the surface, it can determine the color of the object by the light being reflected. However, when you put the color sensor up to a colored light, it shines right into the sensor-portion of the color sensor (the other portion being the LED), making it assume it sees a completely different color. The Color Sensor from Lego Mindstorms kits is simply not capable of doing what you demand.